# How solve the issue of the NERDTree icons displaying incorrectly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, neovim, nerdtree

When I configured my `init.vim` of the `neovim` on my Linux Ubuntu 22.04, I simply copied the file from [here](https://github.com/NeuralNine/config-files/blob/master/init.vim), which uses the `NERDTree` shortcuts as follows:

```
nnoremap <C-f> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTree<CR>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="~"
```

But when I use the shortcut `Ctrl+T` to toggle the `:NERDTreeToggle` function, the display was erratic:
[image]

and [image]

But the desired outlook should be as follows:
[image]

and [image]

I tried adding `:set encoding=UTF-8`, but it still didn't display properly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: It looks like you don't have the proper font installed.  Those are Unicode glyphs that are not in your average font.

Comment: as @TimRoberts said, install [nerd fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/).